# Solve transformation of expected value

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, density-function

I try to solve for $a > 0$ the integral

$$\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ax} f(x) \,dx$$

where $f$ is the density of a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$-distributed random variable (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure) using the knowledge that for $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ we have

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{Z}] = \exp(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})$$

Sadly I can't see how to use this knowledge, since the factor $a$ can't be brought in front of the integral. Also I can't transform the random variable, since this would involve the density as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Complete the square to get a $\mathcal{N}\left(a,1\right)$ distributed random variable times a constant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\mathcal{R}}e^{ax}f_X(x)dx=\int_{\mathcal{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2ax+a^2)}e^{\frac{a^2}{2}}dx=$$

$$=e^{\frac{a^2}{2}}\int_{\mathcal{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2ax+a^2)}dx=e^{\frac{a^2}{2}}\int_{\mathcal{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2}dx=e^{\frac{a^2}{2}}$$